# I want to use a upright freezer instead of regular refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator

Any possible container to use to prevent beer to freeze if I put it in an upright freezer? I’m asking as I’m planning to buy a small upright freezer instead of this small refrigerator so that I can get more freezer space than just refrigeration but I still want to be able to put some drinks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Are you asking how to prevent something from freezing in a freezer? That's the whole point of a freezer.

Comment: You could use an external temperature controller on your freezer.  It takes over the control of the cooling from the freezer's thermostat.  Regulation of the temperature is by turning the freezer's electricity supply on or off - so it's a temperature activated switch.  You can set the desired temperature on the controller.  When you want your freezer to be just a normal freezer again, just remove the controller.   Failing that, you can wire-in your own STC-1000 like controller.  I have a few freezers wired up with these.  They are inexpensive and work well.

Comment: @Kingsley why not just buy a fridge though? If the OP was wanting to re-use a discarded freezer then sure, this works - in fact even with a fridge it's handy since most fridges won't go warm enough for ale 'cellar' temperature.

Comment: @Mr.Boy - I've read that freezers typically have better insulation than a fridge, so require less energy to maintain the set-point (this may not be true, I'm no refrigeration-engineer).  When one opens the led of a chest-freezer, all the cold doesn't fall out.  Being top-loaded, they certainly *are not* so convenient for loading and unloading big fermenters though.  But if you're cellaring 20 litres kegs, etc. they're great.

Comment: @Kingsley I've no idea on the efficiency though in many countries fridges/freezers are strictly regulated/rated so we can probably find that out. You may well be right. Compared to the thermal mass of the keg, losing a bit of cold air is insignificantthough.

Answer (score 1):

Kinglsey has the answer in the comment.

What you are looking for is a way to control the temperature of the freezer to prevent it from going under freezing point.  Many articles explain how to achieve this at a very low cost.

Answer (score 0):

Every container will slowly cool down to freezing temperatures inside the freezer. Thicker isolation will slow this more, but at some point it will get there.

I bought a combination standing freezer/refrigerator. But this is of course not small (2m10/6'8"(?)). However, it can contain a whole lot of drink and a whole lot of frozen food.